# Issue an error when using empty shell variables

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

Sometimes I use, `$PROJECT_HOME/*` to delete all files in the project. When the environment variable, `PROJECT_HOME` is not set (because I did `su` and the new user doesn't have this environment variable set), it starts deleting all files from the root folder. This is apocalyptic.

How can I configure `bash` to throw error, when I use an undefined environment variable in the shell?

Comment: `set -u` will do what you want.

Comment: can you  make it as the answer?

Comment: `[ -z "$PROJECT_HOME" ] || rm -r "$PROJECT_HOME"/*` won't lead to your apocalypse, ever. (`set -u` still may). Check out my answer.

Comment: @PSkocik, i agree, your answer is informative but is not practical to use as it is very long and i would rather avoid initialising empty env.vars

Comment: Of course you wouldn't initialize your vars to empty strings. `[ -z "$VAR" ]` works with an uninitialized `VAR` too. The initialization was just to show the undesirable behavior—My point is, if your vars ever do become initialized to empty strings, in whatever way, and you run `rm -r "$PROJECT_HOME"/*` mistakenly relying on `set -u`, you will get the "apocalyptic" behavior. IHMO, it's better to be safe than sorry when it comes to protecting the entire contents of your computer. `set -u` is not safe.

Comment: "It is very long"? You should not be looking for a *convenient* way to manually perform dangerous operations. Instead, you should create a function, alias, or script to do what you want; in this case, making in an alias from @PSkocik's suggested command will be both safe *and* convenient.

Comment: What if the user sets `PROJECT_HOME=/etc`? Just checking for an empty value is not enough to prevent cataclysm. You shouldn't use variables from untrusted users when running as root.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In POSIX shell, you can use [set -u](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25):

```
#!/bin/sh

set -u
: "${UNSET_VAR}"
```

or using [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
: "${UNSET_VAR?Unset variable}"
```

In your case, you should use `:?` instead of `?` to also fail on set but empty variables:

```
rm -rf -- "${PROJECT_HOME:?PROJECT_HOME empty or unset}"/*
```

Answer (score 17):

```
[ -z "$PROJECT_HOME" ] || rm -r "$PROJECT_HOME"/*
```

This will also catch the case where `PROJECT_HOME` **is** set but doesn't contain anything.

**Example:**

1) This will delete pretty much everything you can delete on your system (barring dotfiles inside `/` (there aren't usually any)):

```
set -u
PROJECT_HOME=
rm -r "$PROJECT_HOME"/*
```

2) This won't do anything:

```
PROJECT_HOME=
[ -z "$PROJECT_HOME" ] || rm -r "$PROJECT_HOME"/*
```

---

Completely removing your project home and recreating it might be another option (if you want to get rid of dotfiles too):

```
#no apocalyptic threats in this scenario
rm -r "$PROJECT_HOME"
mkdir "$_"
```

Comment: `-z` is ok, but since `$PROJECT_HOME` is supposed to be a directory, maybe `-d` would be better. `[[ -d $PROJECT_HOME ]] && rm -r "$PROJECT_HOME"`.

Comment: If PROJECT_HOME is set to a nondirectory, that's an noncatastrophic error, possibly due to a typo. The `-d` check would hide that error. I think it's better if it goes on to `rm` and `rm` complains about it out loud.

Comment: If PROJECT_HOME is set, but the name is not a directory, then `[[ -d $PROJECT_HOME ]] && rm -r "$PROJECT_HOME"` will do nothing, silently. But `[[ -z $PROJECT_HOME ]] || rm -r "$PROJECT_HOME"` will silently delete "$PROJECT_HOME", even if it's a file that is not a directory. Getting an error message is never a problem: `if [[ -d $PROJECT_HOME ]]; then rm -r "$PROJECT_HOME"; else printf '%s is not a directory\n' "$PROJECT_HOME" >&2; fi`

Comment: @kojiro What follows after the check is `rm -r "$PROJECT_HOME"/*`. (notice the /* part). `rm` will always fail with that it PROJECT_HOME isn't a directory. But those are details.

Comment: Now "accidentally" set `PROJECT_HOME="/."` ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If PROJECT_HOME is set to root, the procedure that empties PROJECT_HOME will empty root. That's the expected and perfectly reasonable behavior. And you don't even need that final dot.

Comment: @PSkocik - you're wrong about `rm` failing in every case that `$PROJECT_HOME` doesn't point to a directory file w/ `/*`. And anyway, *all* of the suggestions in this answer are representative of bad habits, in my opinion. I say this because I've learned the hard way to break myself of those very same habits. The simple fact of the matter is - you should really never prune a tree not already rooted in `.` - you just don't do it. In fact, you really shouldn't attempt to do modifications on any files which aren't already`./` here.  Basically I'm saying - prune only from the base, like `find`.

Comment: @mikeserv All you gotta do to prove me wrong is give one single example of a non-zero-length PROJECT_HOME that isn't a directory for which `rm -r $PROJECT_HOME/*` can succeed.

Comment: @PSkocik - that's pretty easy - put the name of a symlink in it.

Comment: @mikeserv OK :D But it's still got to be a DIRECTORY symlink.

Comment: @PSkocik - it's also actually not *expected* or *normal* behavior for `rm` to operate on `/.`. `rm` is spec'd to refuse - even with `-f` - to handle any arg ending with `/..` or `/.` or which is only `.` or `..`. That's another reason why `./.` is the safest place to be when working w/ `rm`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
rm -r "${somevar:-/tmp/or_this_if_somevar_is_empty}"/*
```

There are many variable substitutions, the one above is when "somevar" is empty (and in that case it attempts to delete `/tmp/or_this_if_somevar_is_empty/*` )

Comment: Or: `rm -fr ${ENV_VAR:?suitably caustic message here}/*`, but it might still be worth checking that the value doesn't map to the root directory, noting that there are many ways to subvert simple tests: `//`, `/..`, `/usr/who/../..`, …

Comment: Yes.  If you're going to use a parameter expansion, you may as well use [the one that actually throws an error](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)